# Graceful way of allowing one of two allowed values in string C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have a request class which has the following property

```
        /// <summary>
        /// First time discount flag
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("firstTimeDiscountFlag")]
        public string FirstTimeDiscountFlag { get; set; }
```

I am doing this to check if it is null and has allowed values

```
 if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.FirstTimeDiscountFlag)
   || (request.FirstTimeDiscountFlag.ToUpper() != "Y" && request.FirstTimeDiscountFlag.ToUpper() != "N"))
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

The proper approach is to use a [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) that will serialize a boolean to `Y` or `N` and handle the deserialization too:

```csharp
public class YNBoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value switch
        {
            true => "Y",
            false => "N",
            _ => string.Empty
        });
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value switch
        {
            true => true,
            "Y" => true,
            "y" => true,

            false => false,
            "N" => false,
            "n" => false,

            _ => existingValue
        };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

You use it via the [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm):

```csharp
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(YNBoolConverter))]
    public bool? BoolValue { get; set; }
}
```

Working demo available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_74690756).

Answer (score 1):

You could write this as an expression bodied property like this...

```
public string FirstTimeDiscountFlag { get; set; }
    
public bool IsFirstTimeDiscountFlagValid => 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstTimeDiscountFlag) || "YN".Contains(FirstTimeDiscountFlag.ToUpper());
```

But a better approach might be to investigate the Fluent Validation library (https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) and write a validator for you model class.

Comment: if value will be "YN". What will happen?